# Where are the attributes stored, which are set by servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Below is my servlet:

```
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(request.getParameter("firstname") == null || request.getParameter("lastname") == null){
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");

        request.setAttribute("firstname", firstName);
        request.setAttribute("lastname", lastName);

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Below is my `index.jsp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="servletexample" method="post" >
       <table border="0">
         <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="lastname"  /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my `output.jsp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your first and last name is: </h1>
    <%
        /*String firstName = (String)request.getAttribute("firstname");
        String lastName = (String)request.getAttribute("lastname");*/
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");

        out.print(firstName + " " + lastName);
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

I learnt that, When a webapplication gets loaded, the servletcontainer will create the `ServletContext` once and keep in server's memory. `ServletContext` is a collection of attributes and configurations that apply to the entirety of your web application

As per above servletexample, `request.setattribute` is used to create a new attribute.

1)

Are these attributes stored in `ServletContext`?

2)

What are those attributes and configurations that is stored in `ServletContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three scopes:

1. Application Scope (I.e. SevletContext)
2. Session Scope (I.e. HttpSession)
3. Request Scope (I.e. HttpServletRequest)

Getting ServletContext Object:

1. getServletContext().set attribute("name","value");  //now the name
   attribute will be accessible from any Servlet within the application.

   Getting HttpSession Object:
2. request.getSession(true).set attribute("name2","value");
    //now the name2 attribute will be accessible from current session
3. request.set attribute("name3","value");

   //now the name3 attribute will be accessible anywhere in Servlet or jsp before sending response back to the client.

Ques:where attributes are stored?

Ans: Attributes are stored in a Map(in name-value pair) of respective Scope.
     i.e. Session Map, Request Map and ServletContext Map.

Comment: Why do we need to `request.setattribute(..)` in servlet to pass on information about `firstname` and `lastname` to `output.jsp`? Can't `output.jsp` perform `request.getParameter`  to retrieve those `firstname` & `lastname` values instead of `request.getAtttibute `?

Comment: parameters are different than attributes. getParameter() returns String type, while getAttribute() returns Object type. Suppose you only receive date of birth from the client. you can use request.getParameter("dob") and write logic to calculate user's age and store it in request attribute i.e. request.setAttribute("age") and use request.getAttribute("age") is your JSP.

Comment: also one big differnce between attributes and parameters is  parameters are immutable i.e. they don't have setters methods , i.e setParameter() is not available in the API

Comment: Yes, but Why can't jsp just do `request.getParameter("firstname");` instead of `(String)request.getAttribute("firstname")`?

Comment: You can do that if you have received request parameters from user. I.e. HTML form input tags value.

Comment: As per my above servlet code, I receive request parameters Before I requestdispatch `output.jsp`.  But in jsp, when I tried `request.getParameter()` instead of `request.getAttribute()`, this line `out.print(firstName + " " + lastName);` prints `null null`. Please help me on this!!!

Comment: Add your JSP page which requests your ServletExample Servlet. Does it contains firstname and lastname parameters??

Comment: I have added my `output.jsp` page into the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79292/discussion-between-asside-and-overexchange).

Answer (score 1):

The ServletContext is an object that contains meta informaton about your web application. It will contain attributes that you set. You can access it via the HttpRequest object, like this:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

You can set the attributes for request(as per your example), response and session objects. As well as you can directly set it to context.

```
context.setAttribute("someValue", "aValue");
```

And can retrieve it like

```
Object attribute = context.getAttribute("someValue");
```

The attributes stored in the ServletContext are available to all servlets in your application, and between requests and sessions. That means, that the attributes are available to all visitors of the web application. Session attributes are just available to a single user.

The ServletContext attributes are still stored in the memory of the servlet container. That means that the same problems exists as does with the session attributes, in server clusters.

Answer (score 1):

A web application in java has several scopes Request, Session, Global(ServletContext)

```
request.getAttribute("firstname");
request.getAttribute("lastname");
```

> Are these attributes stored in ServletContext?

`firstname` & `lastname` are stored in the request scope only available for that particular request.

> What are those attributes and configurations that is stored in
>   ServletContext?

Any information which is intended to be shared across all the servlets is stored in a ServletContext. For an instance say you are developing a web application where you want to access the email of administrator in whole application. You want to set this email id @ one location and every Servlet and Jsp can access that email. In that case you will take the help of ServletContext. You can add this email in servletcontext via init parameter in web.xml. Now this value (Email id of administrator) will be available to every Jsp and Servlet in the web application.